# What are the best practices for creating new elements of different type in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list of elements of different types. Each has a toggle which toggles their visibility. Now there are two ways to hide an element either detach it from DOM or set the visibility to hidden.

As I understand Angular still updates hidden elements so this may impact the performance. Is this true? With jQuery one can detach the element from DOM and then attach it again when it needs to be visible. But is this approach even a good practice in Angular?

From reading Angular documentation and its API it gave me an impression that Angular prefers that all templates/HTML are declared at the start and their content is dynamically changed with controllers. So if you want to add/remove elements you'd use an `ng-repeat` directive and then by removing elements from an array in the scope you can add/remove elements from the template. This works well with primitive elements of the same type. However, how does this work if you have a list of elements of different type?

**Edited:**

http://jsfiddle.net/k26bA

An example here would be a list of tools which can be made available with a checkbox. In the example the first approach has a static list of elements which can not be dynamically changed. Which means you need to know in advance which tools will be available.

The second approach has a list in the controller to which you add and remove tools and in the template use `ng-repeat` to iterate over that list and create the tools. However, I'm stuck here as a tool can be a button, a text field, checkbox or even a complex div.

I find it a little hard to have a `model first` here because this is just a part that hides and shows available controls as opposed to displaying a domain model.

A good example of what I'm thinking would be Google Maps where you can hide or minimise various controls on the map.

Comment: It could be helpful if you provide a fiddle oh what you would like to achieve

Comment: you are not thinking `model first`. You modify model and let angular manage DOM updates. Create demo that outlines what you are trying to do.Very unclear what `different type` impact is.

Comment: I didn't want to give a specific example because I wanted to find out an Angular way to create new elements but I guess each case would be different. I added a link to a fiddle which I hope will illustrate what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to familiarize yourself with the [`ng-switch` directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch). The inactive items in an `ng-switch` are entirely unhooked from the DOM, as opposed to an `ng-hide` or `ng-show`, which simply set the CSS styles to show or hide.

Comment: Oh ya thanks for pointing it out. Somehow I missed this directive. It looks like a good way to hook various elements to the DOM conditionally. There's another one I came across called ng-if which can help me with hiding and showing elements. What about dynamically adding different elements to some div/area, do you know any good Angular ways to do it? With ng-switch and ng-if you need to know in advance which elements you're going to have. May be I should create another question for this as your answer pretty much answers my initial question.

Comment: Yes, `ng-if` is also nice. I haven't had the opportunity to work with version 1.2 yet, so `ng-if` isn't in my bag of tricks yet. I need to upgrade my projects =)  Post a link to your new question here and I'll take a look.